# Why does Typescript still cant read push method even after initializing as array ? (ANGULAR2)

Tags: angular, pubnub

Im trying to create a chat application using pubnub and Angular2, but Im stuck at this part.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PubNubAngular } from 'pubnub-angular2';

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
  public uuid: string;
  public message: string;
  public messages = [];  <------------------- Already initialized
  public channel: string[];

  constructor(private pubnub:PubNubAngular) {

    //  .......  ///

    this.pubnub.addListener({
      message: function (m) {
        let msg: object = {
          origin: m.channel,
          timetoken: m.timetoken,
          content: m.message,
          sender: m.sender
        }
        this.messages.push(msg); <-------- PRODUCES A "CANNOT READ PROPERTY 
                                           'PUSH' OF TYPE UNDEFINED IN [NULL]" ERROR
      }
    });
  }
```

Please help, It seems for some reason I cant access the messages array in that part, and probably why it cant detect the push method.

Comment: I don't know what happens above addListener(), but at the line you get the error, this.messages is not what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using arrow function should solve your issue

```
message: (m) => {
  let msg: object = {
    origin: m.channel,
    timetoken: m.timetoken,
    content: m.message,
    sender: m.sender
  }
  this.messages.push(msg); <-------- now this is your component instance
}
```

See more information about arrow function here

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this